# Mixed fractional numbers in C++ boost rational library

Tags: c++, boost

Is it possible to initialize and use mixed fractional numbers in C++ boost rational library?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Always provide at least samples of the intended goal, preferably with the code you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean like here: http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/mixed-number-to-improper-fraction.php then sure:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ea96fca18c2a443)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/rational.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using R = boost::rational<int>;

int main() {
    std::cout << "3 + 5/9: " << 3 + R(5,9) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
3 + 5/9: 32/9
```

If you meant **output formatting**, you could make your own small IO manipulator:

```
template <typename R>
struct as_mixed_wrapper {
    R value;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, as_mixed_wrapper const& w) {
        auto i = boost::rational_cast<typename R::int_type>(w.value);
        return os << i << " " << (w.value - i);
    }
};

template <typename R> as_mixed_wrapper<R> as_mixed(R const& value) {
    return {value};
}
```

And use it like so: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07dfb13f2aa4aeb2)</kbd>**

```
auto n = 3 + R(5,9);
std::cout << n << " would be " << as_mixed(n) << "\n";
```

Which prints

```
32/9 would be 3 5/9
```

### BONUS

Also implementing a quick & dirty stream extraction for the manipulator:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/962dd1b14d4503ec)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/rational.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using R = boost::rational<int>;

    template <typename R>
    struct as_mixed_wrapper {
        R* value;
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, as_mixed_wrapper const& w) {
            auto i = boost::rational_cast<typename R::int_type>(*w.value);
            return os << i << " " << (*w.value - i);
        }

        friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, as_mixed_wrapper const& w) {
            typename R::int_type i, d, n;
            char c;
            if ((is >> i >> d >> c) && (c == '/') && (is >> n))
                *w.value = i + R(d,n);
            return is;
        }
    };

    template <typename R> as_mixed_wrapper<R> as_mixed(R& value) {
        return {&value};
    }

int main() {
    auto n = 3 + R(5,9);
    std::cout << n << " would be " << as_mixed(n) << "\n";

    std::istringstream iss("123 7 / 13");
    if (iss >> as_mixed(n))
        std::cout << n << " would be " << as_mixed(n) << "\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Parse error\n";
}
```

Prints

```
32/9 would be 3 5/9
1606/13 would be 123 7/13
```

Comment: Added stream extraction as a bonus.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I wanted. Thanks @sehe for thorough answer!

Comment: Now that you accepted this, can you still tell us what part of the answer you were after? I'm curious

Comment: Both creating/initializing mixed fractions and especially output formatting as you said. I was going to implement them on my own but I'm not so professional on C++ you know :) I will make use of your code! It will be much more professional then mine )) Thanks again!

Comment: my last question is boost doesn't support mixed fractions yet, right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Mixed fractions do not exists. You can merely have a "mixed" representation of "just rationals".

Comment: Well, I think they are called mixed numbers, I misused the term, sorry. I meant this form 3 5/9 of this fraction 32/9. (an integer and a proper fraction)

Comment: Like I said, that's just a representation. There's no such thing as a mixed number. Maths is maths.

Comment: Maybe I'm expressing incorrectly but could you refer to following links for their definition please: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)#Mixed_numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)#Mixed_numbers), [http://www.bbc.co.uk/skillswise/factsheet/ma17frac-l1-f-what-are-mixed-numbers](http://www.bbc.co.uk/skillswise/factsheet/ma17frac-l1-f-what-are-mixed-numbers), [https://www.khanacademy.org/math/arithmetic/](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/arithmetic/fraction-arithmetic/arith-review-mixed-number/a/mixed-numbers-and-improper-fractions-review)

Comment: That section indeed discusses the many differente [equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)#Equivalent_fractions) representation forms of [abstract fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)#Fractions_in_abstract_mathematics). The [essential rules take ~4 lines](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fraction), which handsomely explain why a library will usually not want to bother with representation. The point of Boost Rational is to be able to enable lossless arithmetic on rational numbers.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks @sehe.